# Value Error when creating dictionary using python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, valueerror

I am a student who is totally new to python and is currently learning it.
So i was asked to create a dictionary from a list which contains a row of data in the file.

```
record = ["Name", "ID", "datetime", "Type", "Lat", "Long", "Central Pressure", "Mean radius gf wind", "Max wind speed", "Comment"]
```

the file is already imported and it consists of many rows of data that correspond to the the element in `record` list.

Example of data:

```
r1 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "100", "10.3"]        
r2 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "", "10.3"]
```

so my code is like

```
def parse_record(record):
key = ["id", "name", "year", "month", "day", "hour", "central pressure",
       "radius", "speed", "lat", "long"]
value = [str(record[1]), str(record[0]), int((record[2][:4]),
         int((record[2])[5:7]),int((record[2])[8:10]),
         int((record[2][10:13]),float(record[6]), 
         float(record[7]),float(record[8]),float(record[4]), float(record[5])]

record_dictionary = dict(zip(key,value))

return record_dictionary
```

I am expecting to get

```
a1 = {"id": "AU190607_01U", "name": "unnamed", "year": 1907, "month": 1,
      "day": 17, "hour": 23,"central pressure": 994.0, "radius": 100.0,
      "speed": 10.3, "lat": -13.0, "long": 146.5}
```

but I get an error message says:

```
int((record[2])[8:10]),int((record[2])[10:13]), float(record[6]), float(record[7]),
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

and also if there is a blank value in data(such as in eg of r2 above), it is supposed to be left out of dictionary, what should i do to achieve this?

Thanks for any help in this!

Comment: You have a `return` statement but I dont see you declaring a function.

Comment: `float(record[...])` where you can replace `...` by any integer between 0 and 9 would throw this exception because you're trying to make a float from a string that has nothing to do with a float. `float(record[6])` is actually `float("Central Pressure")`, hence the error.

Comment: @zezollo, record refers to r1 not key

Comment: It might be easier to `zip` the keys/values together first. Then you can iterate over the values and address type conversion and validation issues afterwards. The code will probably be much simpler and easier to follow.

Comment: @Clock Slave  hi i have edited my code, forgot to put the definiton in front..

Comment: @jiajiahong, your indentation needs to be fixed

Comment: @ClockSlave ermm i cant see an indentation error in the code though? I was trying out the solutions others helped to provide but it still keeps give me the valueError...

Comment: @jiajiahong, i have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing this

```
def parse_record(record):
    key = ["id", "name", "year", "month", "day", "hour", "central pressure",
           "radius", "speed", "lat", "long"]
    record = [i if i else 0 for i in record]
    value = [str(record[1]), str(record[0]), int((record[2])[:4]),
             int((record[2])[5:7]),int((record[2])[8:10]),
             int((record[2])[10:13]),float(record[6]), 
             float(record[7]),float(record[8]),float(record[4]), float(record[5])]

    record_dictionary = dict(zip(key,value))

    return record_dictionary

record = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "", "10.3"]        

r1 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "100", "10.3"]        
r2 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "", "10.3"]  

parse_record(r1)
parse_record(r2)
```

Note that in the output for second record, you will have zero as the value for `radius`. This because there is no value present for this record.

**EDIT**

I have made the changes.

```
def parse_record(record):
    key = ["id", "name", "year", "month", "day", "hour", "central pressure",
           "radius", "speed", "lat", "long"]
    record = [i if i else 0 for i in record]

    value = [str(record[1]), str(record[0]), int((record[2])[:4]),
             int((record[2])[5:7]),int((record[2])[8:10]),
             int((record[2])[10:13]),float(record[6]), 
             float(record[7]),float(record[8]),float(record[4]), float(record[5])]
    _ = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(key,value) if b]
    record_dictionary = dict(_)

    return record_dictionary

record = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "", "10.3"]        

r1 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "100", "10.3"]        
r2 = ["unnamed", "AU190607_01U", "1907-01-17 23:00", "T", "-13", "146.5", "994", "", "10.3"]  

parse_record(r1)
parse_record(r2)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help, may i ask if i want to remove this value from the dictionary , what can i do?

Comment: Which value? And what do you mean by remove? you want to replace it with some other value or you want to drop it from the record?

Comment: its like in r2 for radius it is "", which is empty, and i am supposed to leave it out of the dictionary

Comment: so for r2 i want the dicionary to show a2 = {"id": "AU190607_01U", "name": "unnamed", "year": 1907, "month": 1,
      "day": 17, "hour": 23,"central pressure": 994.0,
      "speed": 10.3, "lat": -13.0, "long": 146.5} so it is drop it from the record i think..?

Comment: hi thanks but may i know why this work? sorry for so many question i am quite confused with python..

Comment: In this line `_ = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(key,value) if b]`, I have kept only those key,value pairs which are not empty.

Comment: feel free accept the answer if my answer has solved your doubts

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in

```
value = […, float(record[7])…]
```

Since in your second value list, `record[7]` is `""` which is not a valid float literal.

Comment: thanks!
what to do to if i want to remove a pair of value and key from the dictionary if the value to the key is "", which is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that will help you with blank values (with not changing types while making dictionary).

```
record_dictionary = {a:b for a,b in zip(key,value) if b != '' }
```

There is a good suggestion above, by @tdube to zip keys and values at first, and only then to change there types.

Comment: new_list = zip(key,value)
record_dictionary = {a: b for a, b in new_list if b != ""}                                         i have tried to zip the two list together but I think this still cannot remove the key when the empty value is detected.. may i ask what is this line supposed to do exactly? thank you.

Comment: @jiajiahong Hi! I just tried it and it worked for me on your example, maybe I misunderstood the task. r1 and r2 are two different rows, which should be in a final result, but there won't be key/value pair with the blank value from r2 - is that right?
What this method does: it makes a dictionary from zipping with a condition, that b (value) is not a blank.